# Reading bytes from compressed PDF file in Java

Tags: java, file, pdf, stream, byte

When I try to read bytes from a normal PDF file into a byte array using "read" function in Java, the byte array is loaded correctly with size same as that of original PDF file.

```
Path file_path = Paths.get("D:\\Zip Test Client", "vadClient1.pdf");
    byte[] ByteArray= Files.readAllBytes(file_path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\newFinalPDF.pdf"));
```

But when I read bytes from the same PDF file located inside a zipped folder, the read function reads only 8843 bytes (original size is 194471) and rest all are 0.

```
zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("D:\\Zip test Server\\ZipTestFolderOnServer.zip"));
        long count = zipFile.size();
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){

            System.out.println("New File starting");
            ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
            InputStream fis =  zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry); 
            byte[] fileToBytes = new byte[(int)zipEntry.getSize()];


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\ContentZipped_"   + zipEntry.getName()));
            fis.read(fileToBytes);
            fos.write(fileToBytes);
            fis.close();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            --count;
        }
```

What is the explanation to this behavior?

EDIT 1:- I am not looking for third party integrations such as Tika or POI.

Comment: How relevant is that these test files happen to be PDFs?

Comment: You're calling `InputStream.read` and ignoring the return value - you appear to be assuming that you can read all the data in a single call to `read`. That's a bad assumption.

Comment: @RadLexus I have .png, .xml, .doc, and .txt located in same zipped folder, and all of them are showing normal behavior.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the update. But this is just a POC snippet, actual API that I am building contains all sorts of exceptions and boundary checking. But the point is, that the number of bytes being read is just 8843, why is that?

Comment: You are probably not reading the full inputStream, read until `fis.read` return `-1` which means the end of stream. Use `Files.readAllBytes` as you did in your first snippet and you should have the full file.

Comment: There's no point in us trying to correct a piece of code which doesn't represent your real code. I've said what's wrong with the code you've presented - `InputStream.read` is never guaranteed to read all the data you've requested before returning. If your *actual* code is the same in terms of the assumption I listed, then that's what's wrong. If you've *really* got a loop and you're calling `read` multiple times until it returns -1 to indicate the end of the stream, then you should update your question to show that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the answer. I'll incorporate the suggestion given by you in my code and update OP if it works.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, your suggestion worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's make it less error prone (and less memory consuming) by simplifying the code, use this to copy the content of your zip entry:

```
try (InputStream fis =  zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)) {
    Files.copy(fis, Paths.get("E:\\ContentZipped_"   + zipEntry.getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class SampleZipExtract {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> tempString = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\abc.zip");
    InputStream input;
    try {

      input = new FileInputStream(file);
      ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(input);
      ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry();

      BodyContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

      Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

      while (entry!= null){

            if(entry.getName().endsWith(".txt") || 
                       entry.getName().endsWith(".pdf")||
                       entry.getName().endsWith(".docx")){
          System.out.println("entry=" + entry.getName() + " " + entry.getSize());
                 parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
                 tempString.add(textHandler.toString());
            }
       }
       zip.close();
       input.close();

       for (String text : tempString) {
       System.out.println("Apache Tika - Converted input string : " + text);
       sbf.append(text);
       System.out.println("Final text from all the three files " + sbf.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am not looking for any third party APIs. I will edit the OP